# Is an Entity Framework Model with Multiple Tables slowing down project?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Let me preface by saying I'm not amazing at entity, but the project models I was handed do not seem correct to me at all.

We have about 4 .edmx files.  The largest one has about 30 tables in it.  Each table has anywhere from 2 navigational properties to 25.

So essentially the diagram looks like a mess.  Submitting / getting anything from the database is very slow.  Not just on the client-to-server level, but also on the server-to-server level.

Is there any way to essentially fix the models to prevent such slow speeds without majorly re-writing the DAL?

Or do we need to slowly edge away from entity by shifting the database calls over to standard DBConnections?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve] .. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered

Comment: I don't feel that this question is answerable as is.  It's much too broad.